# Layout update not working (customer navigation/dashboard)

Tags: layout, layout-update

It seems that I'm missing something elementary here, though I'm not able to spot it.

When trying to add a link to the customer dashboard (from a custom module) the link doesn't show up on the frontend.

Here is my layout update (warranty.xml, in the base/default/layout directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink">
            <name>warranty</name>
            <path>warranty/index/index</path>
            <label>Warranties</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Some config details:

- There is a custom theme being used (all of the layout changes are in a local.xml file)
- Running Enterprise edition (though I don't think this should matter)

What I've tried:

- Disabled Cache
- Copied the warranty.xml to the current theme directory
- Added the  to the local.xml (this seemed to work, but want to do it the right way)

The XML file is being loaded (when xml not formatted correctly the system throws an error)

**Update:**
Since I haven't been able to figure out what is wrong with the syntax (it seems fine to me), I went ahead and used an observer:

Event: `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`

```
public function addLink(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if (!isset($block)) {
        return $this;
    }
        if ($block->getType() == 'customer/account_navigation') {
            $block->addLink('custommod', 'custommod', 'Custom customer page');
        }
}
```

Comment: did you ever fix this?

Comment: @DavidManners no :( used an observer instead, its possible that there is a formatting issue when using phpstorm for making xml files, but couldn't confirm

Comment: shame, I copied over your code and it seemed fine for me, maybe you could share your observer solution incase someone else is having the same issue.

Comment: @DavidManners i'm wondering if it has to do with some file format thing (UTF?) would you have any tips on how to test this out

Comment: I tested your layout update, and it works fine for me, so the syntax is correct (as i guess that your `<layout>` tag is actually closed). Do you have another `warranty.xml` file that could be located in the current design package (for example, `rwd`) ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be, that your file is called before the `customer.xml`, the solution here is to `<depends>` on the `Mage_Customer` module, so your `layout.xml` is included later.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your xml file is merged with other files? Can you paste config.xml of your module or check if for example adding
`<remove name="head" />`
under `<default>` node of your warranty.xml brakes all layouts...

Comment: @jermoon yes it is merged, when i add `<remove name="head" />` it has the desired results